# Tower.js - how to use the minify/combine asset pipeline?

Tags: node.js, assets, towerjs

I understand that I have to create an `assets.coffee` file that configures how to compile and combine files together and the run cake `assets:compile` to actually do it.

However, I tried that and I get the message: `No such task: assets:compile`

A related question - will Tower also handle inserting the files into the actual HTML (for example, a layout, or header or footer view)? Because the complied resource names are random every time, I cannot imagine it being some kind of manual work?

Comment: For the second question: Are you wondering about, if Tower embeds the assets in the HTML?

Comment: @Daniel - yes, exactly - how is that part handled?

Answer (score 0):

The command for compiling assets is `cake assets:bundle`, https://github.com/viatropos/tower/blob/master/test/example/Cakefile#L15, which runs this method: https://github.com/viatropos/tower/blob/master/packages/tower-application/server/assets.coffee#L22